# Maximum value in r

Tags: r, max

I am trying to find the max value for a column in my data table that is of type `integer`. When I run the following code I am returned with 1319.

```
max(flights$dep_time, na.rm = FALSE)
```

The same number is returned when I run summary as well

```
summary(flights$dep_time)
```

I have looked at the csv in Excel and know the maximum value to be 2400. There are also over 100,000 rows that have values greater than 1319 in this column. I am not sure why this is happening and would appreciate help. I've tried changing class to `numeric` and the same thing happens.

Comment: Are you referring to the `flights` dataset from `nycflights13`. If so, then please include this critical information in your main post.

Comment: Without seeing what you've got, it's pretty hard to help. There could be an issue with how you're reading in the data but we don't have much to work with.

Comment: Assuming you are referring to `nycflights13::flights`, I cannot reproduce your issue: `max(flights$dep_time, na.rm = T)` correctly returns `2400`.

Comment: I'm guessing you've made a selection and overwritten your original data at some step prior to running `max()`. See if you can replicate the issue in a totally clean R session.

Comment: It is the nyflights13 data set. I have no idea what is going on because I can get the correct max value for columns of the same integer class but just not for dep_time.

Comment: Try running `str(flights)` and see if your output matches mine: `Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':       336776 obs. of  19 variables`

Comment: This has got to be an issue involving an accidental modification of `nycflights13::flights`. As @thelatemail suggested, you should start from a fresh R terminal (make sure you (1) *don't* resume a previous session, and (2) your global environment is empty); then do `max(nycflights13::flights$dep_time, na.rm = T)`. Alternatively, confirm that `str(flights$dep_time)` returns `int [1:336776] 517 533 542 544 554 554 555 557 557 558 ...`. Your dataset should have more than 300,000 rows (not just "*over 100,000 rows*").

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Hope below solution will work for your query.

convert column integer to as.character and then again convert it to as.numeric then take a max will be useful.

Comment: Why would converting from `integer` to `character` to `integer` solve OPs issues?

Comment: The OP states in the first sentence that the type is `integer`, so there is no need for any type conversion.

Comment: This actually solved the issue. I had to convert the type from factor to character and then to integer.

Comment: @JustinQuinlisk This should *not* have solved your issue. If it did, it means the problem description you posted did not represent your actual problem. You stated that column `dep_time` was an `integer` vector. Converting from `integer` to `character` to `integer` would do nothing (as pointed out by @RHertel). You now claim that your column was in fact a `factor`. This is a different situation.